# Can't copy codes correctly on google chrome Android

Tags: bug

If I try to copy code in Google Chrome, this is what is happening:

**First Image:** Here I select some part of code.

[image]

Then, If I take the leaf to upwards this happens:

**Second Image:**

[image]

I just can't copy the starting of the code (In the above image, the line `from tkinter import *`). The leaf just goes up to the text of the post.

**Video:** [Link](https://streamable.com/98k12a)

**Link to that question:** [How to make Overredirect window work like(eg.Show in Taskbar,Add Minimize Button) normal window in Tkinter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63881179/how-to-make-overredirect-window-work-likeeg-show-in-taskbar-add-minimize-button)

Android version: Android 10
Device: Xiaomi
Google Chrome version: 85.0.4183.81

Comment: FWIW, I'm not convinced this is an SO issue, I have a xiaomi as well and honestly, the leaf control in MIUI is just garbage (like it is in most android phones)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the post with the code you're trying to copy? From the position of the scrollbar, it appears as though there is no more code to copy above `from tkinter import *`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have added the link. You're right, the code started from there. I have edited the question now.

Comment: So, on Chrome 85 on Android 10 on a Pixel 3, I can move the leaf up to the beginning of the `from` of that first line. It's a pain, but as @Nick says, that's Android for you. That, and my thumb being a goodly percentage of the screen size :). I don't think this is something Stack Overflow can fix.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am adding a screen recording so that others can understand it better. May be it's Android specific problem, but I can't seem to reproduce the same behaviour when I am in desktop mode of Chrome Android.

Comment: @HereticMonkey added a screen recording in the post.

Comment: Yeah, that's just Android Chrome. It wasn't always like that; started with an update about 6 months ago, IIRC. It's much easier to copy from the appropriate plaintext source linked on the revisions page: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63881179/revisions. In the banner for each revision, you'll see a "source" link that'll give you the plaintext.

Comment: @Nick I know that copy-paste is a garbage on Android but I had no issues when I used desktop mode in Chrome. Wonder how that works!

Comment: I had no issues with desktop mode with responsiveness _off_, but I did with responsiveness on, I was still able to do it, it was just a little harder. That said, I use FF anyway (and the mobile view)

Comment: @Nick another thing I have noticed that, I no longer see dark mode on Mobile view. SO has turned into that white old look  :( .Don't know whats the matter!

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry, I use desktop responsive view. IIRC the mobile view isn't really worked on any more because the responsive desktop mode is pretty much superior in every way